# Audio not working since Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, drivers

I need help because my audio speakers and jack are not working since I upgraded from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10.

The problem is that Windows doesn't detect any audio device: [image: Windows 10 sound options with no visible playback devices]

I tried to disable the audio device in the device manager in order to install the latest Realtek driver from the Realtek website as well as the old drivers (for Win7/8.1) from the ASUS website but nothing works. The only error I see is this one (translated as "This device can't start" in English):
[image: Windows 10 Device Manager]

My laptop is an ASUS N75SF with Realtek HD definition audio. I know audio devices are working because I have Linux installed on the same laptop and it works with it.

Any ideas?

Comment: So you've downloaded ann tried to install the Realtek drivers from here: http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#1       Another additional location for Asus specific: http://www.driverscape.com/files/misc/Realtek_High_Definition_Audio_64bit_Win7_Win8_Win81_Win10_R279.exe

Comment: `I tried to disable the audio device in the device manager` - the device should be enabled.

Comment: I mean i try to disable/enable and check for driver updates

Comment: a) are you sure that the driver you got is specifically for YOUR laptop?
b) are you sure the drivers are windows 10 compatible? (they should be if they worked in 8.1)

Comment: a) I am not sure. Asus doesn't provide Win10 drivers but i tried the ones for Win 7 without success.
b) Latest drivers from Realtek and those from driverscape are Windows 10 compatible.

Comment: Have you tried to install these drivers in "compatibility mode". Right click on the installer, go to properties, then compatibility tab.